# Scrolling lags on my home page with a few amount of elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-listview

I have a page that I use as the main one, for now it does not include all the planned information, but for some reason it still lags. You can check how it works here: https://dereza-92371.web.app/#/

Here is the full code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> pageitems = [
      Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, right: 70, top: 50, bottom: 30),
        child: Image.asset(siteMode.selectedMode.logoHome),
      ),
      _gallerySwiper(context),
      _expandableDescription(),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 50,
      ),
      _wideBlockFarm(
        "О НАШЕЙ ФЕРМЕ",
        "Подробнее о наших продуктах",
        '',
        BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: const Color(0xff4A9034),
        ),
        context,
      ),
      _wideBlockProducts(
        "ДОСТАВКА",
        "Как работает наша доставка",
        '',
        BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: const Color(0xff4A9034),
        ),
        context,
      ),
      _allLinksBox(context),
    ];

    return Material(
      color: const Color(0xff4A9034),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 370,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: const RepaintBoundary(
                child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                  'assets/Rive/goat.riv',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 210,
            child: DelayedDisplay(
              delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 650),
              child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.bcgColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      blurRadius: 4,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                siteMode.notificationTitle,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 23,
                                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrowBold',
                                  height: 0.9,
                                  color: Color(0xff4A9034),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                siteMode.notificationDescription,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                                  height: 0.95,
                                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        siteMode.notificationIcon,
                        height: 65,
                        width: 65,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DelayedDisplay(
            delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 350),
              child: RepaintBoundary(
                child: Material(
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.bcgColor,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                  shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: ListView.custom(
                    cacheExtent: 500,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      addRepaintBoundaries: true,
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                      childCount: pageitems.length,
                      (context, index) => pageitems[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List homePageImgs = [
  'assets/Home/Home news 1.jpg',
  'assets/Home/Home news 2.jpg',
  'assets/Home/Home news 3.jpg',
];

Widget _gallerySwiper(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40, top: 20),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10 * 7,
      child: Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          homePageImgs[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Container(
                          color: const Color(0xff4A9034),
                          height: 70,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: const [
                              AutoSizeText(
                                'НОВОЕ МЕНЮ 2023!',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                minFontSize: 23,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrowBold',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  height: 0.97,
                                ),
                              ),
                              AutoSizeText(
                                'Новые блюда, сыры, вина и многое другое!',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                minFontSize: 15,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  height: 0.97,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: const Color(0xff4A9034),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              )
            ],
          );
        },
        itemCount: homePageImgs.length,
        viewportFraction: 0.88,
        scale: 0.9,
        pagination: SwiperPagination(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          builder: SwiperCustomPagination(
            builder: (context, config) {
              return DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                      color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                      activeColor: const Color(0xff4A9034),
                      size: 15.0,
                      activeSize: 17.0)
                  .build(context, config);
            },
          ),
        ),
        //control: const SwiperControl(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// Ссылки снизу
Widget _allLinksBox(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      _smallLinkBlock(context, 'НАША ФЕРМА', 'https://kozanostra.info/'),
      const SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      _smallLinkBlock(context, 'НАШ ИНТЕРНЕТ МАГАЗИН',
          'https://kozanostrashop.ru/shop/syry'),
    ]),
  );
}

Widget _smallLinkBlock(context, text, link) {
  return Container(
    height: 120,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 25,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: siteMode.selectedMode.bcgColor,
      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: const Color(0xff4A9034)),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            child: Center(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                maxLines: 2,
                minFontSize: 18,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrowBold',
                  color: Color(0xff4A9034),
                  height: 0.97,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff4A9034),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
            child: const AutoSizeText(
              'ПЕРЕЙТИ',
              maxLines: 1,
              minFontSize: 13,
              maxFontSize: 22,
              wrapWords: false,
              softWrap: false,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              launchUrl(Uri.parse(link));
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

//  Широкий блок Продукты
Widget _wideBlockFarm(text, description, svg, decoration, context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
    child: Hero(
      tag: text,
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: decoration,
        child: Material(
          color: decoration.color,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/Home/Farm.png',
                      filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        text,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        minFontSize: 13,
                        maxFontSize: 22,
                        wrapWords: false,
                        softWrap: false,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        description,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          height: 0.9,
                          fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                  size: 50,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

//  Широкий блок Продукты
Widget _wideBlockProducts(text, description, svg, decoration, context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
    child: Hero(
      tag: text,
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: decoration,
        child: Material(
          color: decoration.color,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/Home/Products.png',
                      filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        text,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        minFontSize: 15,
                        maxFontSize: 22,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        description,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                          height: 0.9,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                  size: 50,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _expandableDescription() {
  return ExpandableNotifier(
    // <-- Provides ExpandableController to its children
    child: Expandable(
      collapsed: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                'О КАФЕ DEREZA',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrowBold',
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Как известно, самый короткий путь – это прямой. Именно так рассудили на подмосковной сырной ферме «Коза Ностра», и решили стать ближе к Москве, открыв уютный ресторан на Бауманской.\n\nКак и положено ресторану при ферме, преобладают здесь продукты собственного производства – многочисленные козьи сыры разной степени выдержки и молочный козленок. С последним готовят эмпанадас, а еще запекают в чугунке с розмарином, чесноком и картофелем.',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ExpandableButton(
              child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 25),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: const Color(0xff4A9034),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'ПОДРОБНЕЕ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      expanded: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                'О КАФЕ DEREZA',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrowBold',
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Как известно, самый короткий путь – это прямой. Именно так рассудили на подмосковной сырной ферме «Коза Ностра», и решили стать ближе к Москве, открыв уютный ресторан на Бауманской.\n\nКак и положено ресторану при ферме, преобладают здесь продукты собственного производства – многочисленные козьи сыры разной степени выдержки и молочный козленок. С последним готовят эмпанадас, а еще запекают в чугунке с розмарином, чесноком и картофелем.\n\nКоронное блюдо, без сомнения, запеченная в большой сковороде лопатка козленка на двоих. Подают ее с пряными сезонными корнеплодами и наваристым, ароматным бульоном, заслуживающим особого упоминания. Сырам же нашли применение практически в каждом блюде меню – тут и брускетты с шевром и тыквой и «равиоли» из печеной свеклы с мягким козьим сыром и фирменные сырные конфеты.\n\nНа десерт непременно стоит попробовать домашнее мороженое из козьего молока с кедровыми орехами или медовик с шевром. В винной карте особый реверанс в сторону «темпранильо» и «совиньонов».',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: siteMode.selectedMode.textColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// Герой широкого блока
class _AwardsHero extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  const _AwardsHero({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AwardsHeroState createState() => _AwardsHeroState();
}

class _AwardsHeroState extends State<_AwardsHero> {
  var choice = "НАШИ ПАРТНЕРЫ";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: widget.text,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFAD8A6E),
        body: RepaintBoundary(
          child: DelayedDisplay(
            delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            fadingDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              elevation: 0,
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2C2513),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
                          child: const AutoSizeText(
                            'НАЗАД',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            minFontSize: 18,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It gets pretty laggy when you scroll and I am not able to find what causes it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using widget function is bad practice and will definitely affects performance.

Try converting them to class widgets, so flutter can cache them and won’t lead to unnecessary rebuilds.

Comment: Changed it, thank you! Any more advices?

Comment: @Feinliebe Use stateful widgets only when you need it. And use library like extended_image to cache images.